# Unable to access variable within function

Tags: bash, xargs

I have a below code, Where function `copy_from_tar` unable to access the variables defined outside the program. `copy_from_tar` is not echoing the `$file` or `${id_from_doc[@]}` but after entering the function its showing blank output.

I am looking to access `$file` and `$id_from_doc` and which is defined outside function. If anybody has suggestions to overcome this issue please let me know.

```
id_from_doc=(1 2)
file='file/path'
copy_from_tar(){
echo 'entered func'
echo ${id_from_doc[@]}
echo $file
}

export -f copy_from_tar
echo 'sample' | xargs -I % bash -c 'copy_from_tar %'
```

Answer (score 0):

Export variables also. Or (the better way) use `while` loop as follows:

```
id_from_doc=(1 2)
file='file/path'
copy_from_tar(){
    echo 'entered func'
    echo "${id_from_doc[@]}"
    echo $file
}

echo 'sample' | while read f
do
    copy_from_tar "$f"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your logic. Eliminate the explicit subcall to `bash` unless there's a good reason for it that you didn't list here, and rewrite your function to handle the iterations inside it.

```
export id_from_doc=(1 2)
file='file/path'
copy_from_tar(){
    echo 'entered func'
    echo "${id_from_doc[@]}"
    echo $file

    for f in "${id_from_doc[@]}" # or whatever you really wanted
    do  : whatever logic was going to be here - e.g.
        foo-program "$f" "$file" > "$f.ext"
    done
}
```

And if possible (it's virtually always possible), use argument passing instead of globals.